# "The 'timeframe' argument is incompatible with functions that have side effects" – what does it mean?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I moved my rich VWAP indicator out to a Pane to avoid making too big mess on the chart but here in the Pane, I obviously don't see the price (close) there. So I decided to draw it using a `box()`.

```
var box PriceRectangular = na
if(na(PriceRectangular))
    PriceRectangular := box.new(left=bar_index, top=close, right=bar_index, bottom=close, border_color=#8888880a, border_width=2, bgcolor=#00000000, extend=extend.right)
    box.set_left(PriceRectangular, bar_index)
    box.set_border_width(PriceRectangular, 2)
    box.set_top(PriceRectangular, close)
    box.set_right(PriceRectangular, bar_index)
    box.set_bottom(PriceRectangular, close)
    box.set_border_color(PriceRectangular, #8888880a)
    box.set_bgcolor(PriceRectangular, #00000000)
    box.set_extend(PriceRectangular, extend.right)
else
    box.set_left(PriceRectangular, bar_index)
    box.set_border_width(PriceRectangular, 2)
    box.set_top(PriceRectangular, close)
    box.set_right(PriceRectangular, bar_index)
    box.set_bottom(PriceRectangular, close)
    box.set_border_color(PriceRectangular, #8888880a)
    box.set_bgcolor(PriceRectangular, #00000000)
    box.set_extend(PriceRectangular, extend.right)
```

The code itself works elsewhere (on-chart) but here, it fails with the error message above. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will mostly have this issue if you are using any drawing objects. It means that, Tradingview is unable to do a multitimeframe anlaysis of your code automatically.

To get rid of this error, you need to remove the statements `timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true` from your `indicator()` call.

If you really need multi timeframe analysis, you should do that yourself by using [security()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Context_switching_the_security_function.html) function.